# How to transfer the data from multiple worksheets with multiple workbooks into template workbook based on column headers via vba excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a newbie for vba excel actually I just start to learn it 2 weeks ago. I was assigned for one assignment. Honestly, I can't use the real data then I made the new one that near for my needed.

First, I have 2  data workbooks, named "list" and "book", these workbooks have many worksheets. I wrote the vba code in another workbook "command" for browse theme after that I want to transfer the data from them (a lot data) via my workbook "command" and link to the template workbook.

Second, the problem is the worksheets have the merge cell header and subheading. I want to transfer the data by matching the subheading. I mean "NOT" to match by position like .range("A1:C2").

---

Workbook1 "List" and Worksheet  "personal"

```
  Full name        |     Personal profile      |   >> merge cell header
```

----------------------------|----------------------------------------|

first   |   last       | ID.| year | major | grade     |   >> subheading

---

Workbook2 "book" and Worksheet 1 "data"

```
  Personal Profile      |               |          |
```

------------------------------------|       University     |    Hobby    |

year  | major |ID.|grade    |               |          |

Workbook2 "book" and Worksheet 2 "Freshmen"

```
 Full name      |       Gender       |         |            |
```

--------------------|--------------------|  Hobby  | University |

first   |   last    |   male  | female   |         |            |

---

and

Workbook3 "template" and Worksheet 1 "name"

```
 Full name      |
```

--------------------|

first   |   last    |

Workbook3 "template" and Worksheet 2 "profile"

```
         |      Personal Profile         |
```

University   |---------------------------------------------|

```
         |  year | major | ID. |  grade  |
```

Workbook3 "template" and Worksheet 3 "hobby"

```
  |        |      Gender       |
```

ID.  | Hobby  | ------------------|

```
  |        |  male  |  female  |
```

---

Can anyone help me please??
Sorry, my English isn't good.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: In the two weeks that you have been working on this assignment, what code have you written?  Please post it and tell us what is not working the way it should be working.